# Sequelize Associations Not Working with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js, associations

I am going to provide some code since it might be hard to follow what is going on. Essentially, my Express API doesn't return any associations even though my database thinks there are.

High level quickly: I am trying to get an assocation between two models Users and Donations, One-To-Many.

Here is my User Model (simplified):

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model, BuildOptions, Optional, Association, } from "sequelize";

// These are all the attributes in the User model
export interface UserAttributes {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}

// Optional properties, sequelize has the ability to fill these in itself
interface UserCreationAttributes
    extends Optional<
        UserAttributes,
        "id"
    > {}

// Creates the final type interface for the UserModel
export interface UserModel
    extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>,
        UserAttributes {}

// Creates the User class as an extended type of a general model and UserModel
export class User extends Model<UserModel, UserAttributes> {
    // Public properties
    public id!: number;
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;

    // Timestamps
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

    // Associations
    public static associations: {
        donations: Association<User, Donation>;
    };
}

// Creates a static type used for our factory function
export type UserStatic = typeof Model & {
    new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): UserModel;
};

// This function is responsible for generating the "User" model
export function userFactory(sequelize: Sequelize): UserStatic {
    return <UserStatic>sequelize.define(
        "users",
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            firstName: {
                type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
                allowNull: false,
                validate: { notEmpty: true },
            },
            lastName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                validate: { notEmpty: true },
            },
        });
    }
```

Donation Model is set up largely the same way, I don't want to flood you with code so I will just go to the part where I do the associations.

```
// Import the factory functions and sequelize instance, called "db" here
import { donationFactory } from "./Donation";
import { userFactory } from "./User";
import { db } from "../db";

// The Factory functions expect a Sequelize instance as a parameter
const User = userFactory(db);
const Donation = donationFactory(db);
const DonationsRecipients = donationsRecipientsFactory(db);

// Associations
Donation.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Donation);

// Export model
export const model = {
    Donation,
    DonationsRecipients,
    User,
};
```

Okay, so you can see there I am declaring a very simple One-to-Many relationship between the Donation and User models. Below, I will show you my code for my express route.

```
// Get all donors
userGetRoutes.get("/donors", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const users = await User.findAll({
            where: { isDonor: true },
            include: [{ model: Donation }],
        });
        res.status(200).send(users);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

But I only get this!!! The included donations are not there... I cannot access the donation objects
[image: api doesn't find the included donation objects]

And what is even weirder is that Postico thinks there IS an association. You can tell because when you click the little table in my Donation model, the associated user pops up (Monica Moneybags).
[image: the association exists in Postgres]

So... what gives??

EDIT:
Okay so I've made some progress. I got user instances to be able to call "getDonations()" and other magic methods, which do in fact return the donations.

To do this, I adjusted my UserModel and User classes to look like this:

```
import {
    Sequelize,
    DataTypes,
    Model,
    BuildOptions,
    Optional,
    Association,
    HasManyGetAssociationsMixin,
    HasManyAddAssociationMixin,
    HasManyHasAssociationMixin,
    HasManyCountAssociationsMixin,
    HasManyCreateAssociationMixin,
} from "sequelize";

/ Creates the final type interface for the UserModel
export interface UserModel
    extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>,
        UserAttributes {
    donations: DonationModel[];
    getDonations(): HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Donation>; // Note the null assertions!
    addDonation(): HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Donation, number>;
    hasDonation(): HasManyHasAssociationMixin<Donation, number>;
    countDonations(: HasManyCountAssociationsMixin;
    createDonation(): HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<Donation>;
}

// Creates the Donation classs as an extended type of a general model and UserModel
export class User extends Model<UserModel, UserAttributes> {
    // Public properties
    public id!: number;
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;

    // Timestamps
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

    // Associations
    //
    // Since TS cannot determine model association at compile time
    // we have to declare them here purely virtually
    // these will not exist until `Model.init` was called.
    public getDonations!: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Donation>; // Note the null assertions!
    public addDonation!: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Donation, number>;
    public hasDonation!: HasManyHasAssociationMixin<Donation, number>;
    public countDonations!: HasManyCountAssociationsMixin;
    public createDonation!: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<Donation>;

    public readonly donations?: Donation[]; // Note this is optional since it's only populated when explicitly requested in code

    public static associations: {
        donations: Association<User, Donation>;
    };
}
```

Still though, inclusions do not work on called like:

```
const users = await User.findOne({
            where: { isDonor: true },
            include: [{ model: Donation }],
        });
```

It just returns an empty array in the "donations" property :/

Comment: You aren't using that 'User' class anywhere. So how come the find query returns a 'donations' key in the object!!

Anyways, i am using sequalize-typescript to reduce the code length but the logic is somewhat similar. Inside your find query try include:[Donation] or include:[{model:Donation, as: 'donations' }]