# Function Magic Sequelize not exist

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm a beginner in TypeScript and recently started studying the Sequelize ORM model. I had already done a few projects with Sequelize using plain JavaScript, but I decided to give it a try using TypeScript. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now.

I'm Brazilian, so some variables may be in Portuguese. If you have any questions related to that, I can clarify in the comments.

OS : Win 10

Problem:
My PostgreSQL database has 3 entities: "users," "movies," and "users_movies." I have already created the routes, controllers, and services for users and movies. However, when I try to add movies to my users, it gives me an error saying that the association function of Sequelize does not exist.

erro:
`[{"resource": "/c:/Users/pc/Documents/GitHub/trybeJava/EstudosTs/projetoSequelize/src/service/UsuarioFilmeService.ts",     "owner": "typescript",  "code": "2339",     "severity": 8,  "message": "Property 'addFilme' does not exist on type 'Usuario'.",     "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 25,  "startColumn": 21,  "endLineNumber": 25,    "endColumn": 29 }]`

erro message: `Property 'addFilme' does not exist on type 'Usuario'.`

I believe my database configuration file is correct because the endpoints for users and movies are successfully creating and retrieving data. The problem seems to be with the last implemented route, api/userFilme.

Server.ts (arquivo para inciar aplicação)

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import userRoute from './routes/UserRoute'
import filmeRoute from './routes/FilmeRoute'
import userFilmeRoute from './routes/UserFilmeRoute'
import database from './database'

class App {
  public express: express.Application

  public constructor () {
    this.express = express()
    this.index()
  }

  private index (): void {
    this.express.use(express.json())
    this.express.use(cors())
    this.express.listen(3333, () => {
      console.log('rodando')
    })
    this.route()
    this.dataBase()
  }

  private middleware (): void {
  }

  private dataBase (): void {
    database.getConection()
  }

  private route (): void {
    this.express.use('/api/user', userRoute)
    this.express.use('/api/filme', filmeRoute)

//Here
    this.express.use('/api/userFilme', userFilmeRoute)
  }
}

export default new App()
```

The route, in turn, sends the request to the UserFilmeController, which has a method to create a relationship between a user and a movie.

```
  public async addMovieToUser (): Promise<ResponseDto<UserMoviesFavorite>> {
    const sequelize = Connection.getConection()
    const transaction = await sequelize.transaction()

    try {
      const usuario = await Usuario.findByPk(this.idUser)
      const filme = await Filme.findByPk(this.idFilme)
      // bem aqui o erro
      await usuario.addFilme(filme, { transaction })

      await transaction.commit()

      return {
        status: 200,
        message: 'Filme adcionado como favorito'
      }
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback()

      return {
        status: 500,
        message: error

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line where I add the movie simply doesn't exist because, in JavaScript, it works perfectly fine like this. Below, I will provide my models and migrations for reference.

## Model Usuario.ts

```
import { Model, DataTypes, type Sequelize } from 'sequelize'

class Usuario extends Model {
  static associate (models): void {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Filme, { foreignKey: 'id_usuario', through: 'usuarios_filmes', as: 'filmes' })
  }

  static initTable (connection: Sequelize): void {
    this.init(
      {
        nome: DataTypes.STRING,
        idade: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      {
        sequelize: connection,
        modelName: 'Usuario',
        tableName: 'usuarios'
      }
    )
  }
}

export default Usuario
```

## Model Filme.ts

```
import { Model, DataTypes, type Sequelize } from 'sequelize'

class Filme extends Model {
  public id!: number
  public titulo!: string
  public diretor!: string
  public nota!: number

  static associate (models): void {
    this.belongsToMany(models.Usuario, { foreignKey: 'id_filme', through: 'usuarios_filmes', as: 'usuarios' })
  }

  static initTable (connection: Sequelize): void {
    this.init(
      {
        titulo: DataTypes.STRING,
        diretor: DataTypes.STRING,
        nota: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      {
        sequelize: connection,
        modelName: 'Filme',
        tableName: 'filmes'
      }
    )
  }
}

export default Filme
```

**Migration usuarios_filmes**

```
'use strict'

/\*\* @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} \*/
module.exports = {
up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) =\> {
await queryInterface.createTable('usuarios_filmes', {
id: {
allowNull: false,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true,
type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
id_usuario: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
model: 'usuarios',
key: 'id'
},
onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
onDelete: 'CASCADE',
allowNull: false
},
id_filme: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
model: 'filmes',
key: 'id'
},
onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
onDelete: 'CASCADE',
allowNull: false
},
created_at: {
allowNull: false,
type: Sequelize.DATE
},
updated_at: {
allowNull: false,
type: Sequelize.DATE
}
})
},

down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) =\> {
await queryInterface.dropTable('usuarios_filmes')
}
}
```

I wanted to clarify that when calling the addFilme method, a new row should be added to the usuarios_filmes table. For example, if I pass 1 and 1, it means that user 1 likes movie 1, and that should be reflected in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may solve your problem, but it helped me in a similar situation.

I had 2 models, `User` and `Product`, with a one to many association. I wanted to use a req.user.createProduct magic method, which works in JS but not in TS.
To make it work I had to implement the methods names in my User class.

I post you my `User` model, which may better clarify what I mean:

```
import {
  CreationOptional,
  DataTypes,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  Model,
  Association,
  HasManyGetAssociationsMixin,
  HasManyCreateAssociationMixin,
} from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../util/database";
import Product from "./product";

class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare username: string;
  declare email: string;

  public getProducts!: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Product>;
  public createProduct!: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<Product>;

  public readonly products?: Product[];

  public static associations: {
    products: Association<User, Product>;
  };
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(120),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: "users",
    paranoid: true,
    deletedAt: "destroyTime",
  }
);

export default User;
```

As you see, in line 20 I had to manually add the createProduct method, which is created by sequelize, but I had to make explicit to let TS aware of its existence.

I found this solution reading the question made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69018986/sequelize-associations-not-working-with-typescript)